# Unable to satisfy interface contract

Tags: c#, .net

I have an interface and a class that implements said interface. Visual Studio doesn't realize I'm implementing one specific method the interface requires. I only get the error when I build. Resharper isn't alerting me to any issues with my code and everything seems correct.

My interface

```
public interface IViewFactory
{
    IDpaView MakeDpaView();
    IFileSelectorView MakeFileSelectorView(IFileService fileService);
    IDelqReportView MakeDelqReportView();
}
```

Implementation

```
public class ViewFactory : IViewFactory
{
    public IDpaView MakeDpaView() {
        return new DpaView();
    }

    public IFileSelectorView MakeFileSelectorView(IFileService fileService) {
        var fileSelectorView = new FileSelectorView {
            FileService = fileService
        };

        return fileSelectorView;
    }

    public IDelqReportView MakeDelqReportView() {
        return new DelqReportView();
    }
}
```

Implementation of IFileSelectorView

```
public partial class FileSelectorView : Form, IFileSelectorView
{
    public FileSelectorView() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IFileService FileService {
        set { fileSelector.FileService = value; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<PathSelectedEventArgs> PathSelected;

    private void fileSelector_PathSelected(object sender, PathSelectedEventArgs e) {
        if (PathSelected == null)
            return;

        PathSelected(this, e);
    }
}
```

The other methods I didn't show in `ViewFactory` work just fine. The issue is that when I build, I get

> 'name.space.DPA.Win.ViewFactory' does not implement interface member 'name.space.Presentation.IViewFactory.MakeFileSelectorView()'...

but it does implement the method. What gives?

Comment: Do you have multiple conflicting class names in the project, `IFileService` or `IFileSelectorView`?

Comment: What happens if you rename the method to explicitly implement the interface like this `public IFileSelectorView IViewFactory.MakeFileSelectorView(IFileService fileService)`?

Comment: Takes care of the error but introduces another: `The modifier 'public' is not valid for explicit interface implementation.`

Comment: Remove the `public` keyword then!

Comment: I need it to be `public`. Out of curiosity, I removed `public` but looks like I'm back to the same error from the start alone with `'IViewFactory.MakeFileSelectorView' in explicit interface declaration is not a member of interface`.

Comment: Sounds like you have some sort of naming conflict going on. Can you navigate to the definition of all the items and confirm they are coming from the same place?

Comment: Show your ENTIRE class that implements the interface

Comment: @Ahmedilyas - edited question for you.

Comment: Have VS auto-generate the interface implementation.  That will stub it out for you.  If you have multiple types with the same name, this should make it obvious what's going on.

Comment: @Servy - Tried this but I'm still getting same error. I'm fairly sure it's not a naming conflict. I've searched the entire solution with Resharper for anything relevant and I'm not finding anything named the same.

Comment: Last resort - clean build, reopen VS?

Comment: @DavidG - Already tried. I'm going to give my pc a full restart. I really think this is caused by some strangeness outside my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A physical computer restart fixed my issue. I had tried multiple clean builds and restart Visual Studio multiple times but I guess sometimes there's nothing like a complete reboot?